# Obtaining date time from browser without Javascript

Tags: html, css, datetime

I'm working on a CSS/HTML only project, and I'm wondering if there is a way where I can obtain the local date/time on the browser without the use of JavaScript?

I know there's Server Side Includes, but wouldn't the HTML file have to reside on a server like APACHE for this to work?

I'm basically looking to splice the time component into an HHMMSS format, and possibly split this further into six individual values that can be stored in `<input type="hidden" name="digitX" value="y">` tags, where `x` is the xth digit in the HHMMSS number and `y` is the value of the digit...

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without _some_ use of javascript. Is there a particular reason why you can't use javascript?

Comment: @thgaskell It's not a question of "can't", but rather, "won't"... This project is focusing on what HTML5 and CSS are capable of in a no-script environment... So this is the research part of the project...

Answer (score 2):

When using includes (server side) you can't take the local time users, It would use the server time, if it doesn't matter gets the user time you can use a server side language like php and create some inputs and put each value inside.

Comment: Thanks Isaac, but as I mentioned in my original posting of the question, this is meant to be a CSS/HTML project only... :)

Comment: It's only an option... but only with HTML you can't do that, needs JS.